# After adding an Image from gallery after opening my app again it crashes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

so after uploading my `image` from gallery my app works fine, but when i try to close and open my app again, on debug console it throws this error `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{ce75251 30290:eu.tuto.youtubeproject/u0a447} (pid=30290, uid=10447) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs` here is my code

MainActivity.kt

```
        package eu.tuto.youtubeproject

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint
    import android.app.Dialog
    import android.net.Uri
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.os.Environment
    import android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.*
    import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
    import androidx.activity.viewModels
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate
    import androidx.core.net.toUri
    import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.Companion.installSplashScreen
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
    import eu.tuto.youtubeproject.ViewModels.SplashScreenViewModel
    import eu.tuto.youtubeproject.data.ListData
    import eu.tuto.youtubeproject.ViewModels.VideoViewModel
    import eu.tuto.youtubeproject.fragments.*
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.popup.view.*
    import org.w3c.dom.Text


    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private var dialogView: View? = null

        private lateinit var mUserViewModel: VideoViewModel
        private val mSplashScreenViewModel: SplashScreenViewModel by viewModels()





        private val getPreviewImage = //get image from gallery
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
                if (uri != null) {
                    dialogView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.imageUriHolder)?.text = uri.toString() //URI holder doesn't work
                    dialogView?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageChange)?.setImageURI(uri) // set imageURI as Thumbnail
                } else {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "URI not present")
                }
            }


        private val getPreviewVideo =//get video from gallery
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
                if (uri != null) {
                    dialogView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.videoUriHolder)?.text = uri.toString() //videoURI holder doesn't work
                    dialogView?.findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.videoChange)?.setVideoURI(uri) // set videoURi as video
                } else {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "URI not present")
                }
            }





        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


            installSplashScreen().apply {
                setKeepOnScreenCondition {
                    mSplashScreenViewModel.isLoading.value
                }
            }


            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            supportActionBar?.hide()




            bottomNavigationView.background = null
            bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.placeholder).isEnabled = false
            replaceFragment(HomeFragment()) //base fragment

            popupAddButton.setOnClickListener {
                showDialog()
            }
            bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { // navigation bar
                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.home -> replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
                    R.id.player -> replaceFragment(PlayerFragment())
                    R.id.profile -> replaceFragment(ProfileFragment())
                    R.id.settings -> replaceFragment(SettingsFragment())
                }
                true
            }
        }






        private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
            val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            transaction.commit()
        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams", "CutPasteId")
        private fun showDialog() { //this is for popupWindow
            dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null)
            mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[VideoViewModel::class.java]


            val dialog = Dialog(this)


            val titleEditText = dialogView?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.titleEdit) //popUp edit field title
            val descEditText = dialogView?.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.description) //popUp edit field description



            dialogView?.addImage?.setOnClickListener { //opens gallery where you can pick image
                getPreviewImage.launch("image/*")
            }

            dialogView?.addVideo?.setOnClickListener { //opens gallery where you can pick video
                getPreviewVideo.launch("video/*")
            }

            dialogView?.addButton?.setOnClickListener {
                AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
                if (titleEditText?.text?.isEmpty() == true || descEditText?.text?.isEmpty() == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "add required data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {

                    //all variables bellow add specific data to database
                    val addTitleToDatabase = titleEditText?.text.toString()
                    val addDescToDatabase = descEditText?.text.toString()
                    val addImageToDatabase = dialogView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.imageUriHolder)?.text.toString()
                    val addVideoToDatabase = dialogView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.videoUriHolder)?.text.toString()

                    val video = ListData(
                        0,
                        addTitleToDatabase,
                        addDescToDatabase,
                        addImageToDatabase,
                        addVideoToDatabase
                    )
                    mUserViewModel.addUser(video)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Successfully added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
            dialog.setContentView(dialogView!!)
            dialog.show()
        }
    }
```

RecyclerAdapter.kt

```
    package eu.tuto.youtubeproject

import android.app.VoiceInteractor
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
import android.net.Uri
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult
import androidx.core.net.toUri
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import eu.tuto.youtubeproject.databinding.CardLayoutBinding
import eu.tuto.youtubeproject.data.ListData
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.card_layout.view.*
const val PICK_FILE = 1
class RecyclerAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var oldList = emptyList<ListData>()



    inner class MyViewHolder(binding: CardLayoutBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(CardLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = oldList[position]

        holder.itemView.tv_id.text = currentItem.id.toString()
        holder.itemView.tv_title.text = currentItem.title
        holder.itemView.tv_description.text = currentItem.description
        holder.itemView.tv_thumbnail.setImageURI(currentItem.image.toUri())
        holder.itemView.tv_Video.setVideoURI(currentItem.Video.toUri())
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return oldList.size
    }
    fun setData(newList: List<ListData>){
        val diffUtil = eu.tuto.youtubeproject.data.DiffUtil(oldList, newList)
        val diffResults = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffUtil)
        oldList = newList
        diffResults.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: Switch from `GetContent` to `OpenDocument` and use `takePersistableUriPermission()` to be able to use the `Uri` in future runs of your app: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: @CommonsWare where i need to use `takePersistableUriPermission()`?

Comment: In your `registerForActivityResult()` callback lambda expression.